# MYSQL UPDATE in PHP using AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: php, sql, aes

I am trying to do a basic mysql update using AES_ENCRYPT in PHP but I cant get it work.
Here is my full code:

```
$key = "bac09c63f34c9845c707228b20cac5e0";
$query = " SELECT id, aes_decrypt(Column1, '$key') AS Column1, aes_decrypt(Column2, '$key') AS Column2 FROM parent WHERE Request = '{$Request}' ORDER BY ID ASC;";
$resultSet = mysql_query($query, $DB);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)) {
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $rows[] = $row["Request"];
    $Column1 = $row["Column1"];
    $Column2 = $row["Column2"];

$SQL = "UPDATE parent SET Column1 = AES_ENCRYPT('$Column1','$key'), Column2 = AES_ENCRYPT('$Column2','$key') WHERE Parent_ID = '$id';";
        if (!mysql_query($SQL, $DB))
            die("Query Failed $SQL");
    }
```

PHP error log is fine, there is no error. Only this:

```
Query Failed 
UPDATE parent SET Column1 = AES_ENCRYPT('722225374673255299521908919676768...etc','bac09c63f34c9845c707228b20cac5e0')
```

Comment: Try to change it to this: `UPDATE parent SET Column1 = AES_ENCRYPT('$Column1','$key'), Column2 = AES_ENCRYPT('$Column2','$key')  WHERE Parent_ID = '$id';`

Comment: Show the exact error message you're getting from PHP, e.g, the output of `mysql_error()`, and the full text of the query you're running. We can't do our jobs if you don't provide full details.

Comment: @sife: throwing random quotes into the mix is pointless, especially if Parent_ID is an int field. Don't rearrange the deckchairs on the titanic. `{}` around vars is valid php syntax, and in fact required in certain cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query -

```
UPDATE parent SET Column1 = AES_ENCRYPT('$Column1','$key'), Column2 = AES_ENCRYPT('$Column2','$key') WHERE Parent_ID = $id;
```